# Multiple nuget respoitory(TargetFramework specific) or Single Respository

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-server

We are in the process of creating nuget packages for all of our .net framework inhouse libraries and we want to create the libraries targetting multiple .Net framework.

We are confused like, do we need to have separate nuget repository for each .Net target framework or a Single respository with all TargetFramework libraries. And we want to know the pros and cons of both approaches.And we have following questions

### TargetFramework Specific Repo

1. Then we will end up with multiple nuget sources.
2. Whenever we want to upgrade to newer version then we need to create another source for that .Net framework.?
3. Is this right approach to follow this method.?

### Single Repo

1. How the consumer will know wcich version is targetting which .Net framework.?
2. If we need to fix anything with the lowest version targetting branch and if we build that it will have latest version number than the one build with latest target framework.

Please let us know the right approach to have a enterprise nuget repository..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically your nuget packages will have multiple targets within them.

Comment: Thank you Erik for the suggestion we also considered that option.. Thanks again